# Removing Only Selected list item from local storage - Pure JS

Tags: javascript, storage, local

I am facing a bit of trouble here. I am trying to create a to-do list with local storage but the only things I got to work are adding list item it to the local storage and deleting **all items** from the local storage but I can't delete a single SELECTED item out from the list. Can someone help me figure:

1) Removing a selected single item from the list.
2) Putting Checkbox before the List Text.
3) On clicking checkbox, toggle class list "strike" and remembering it on load/page refresh.

Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>To-do's list</h1>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="textBox">
            <button id="enterBtn" type="button">Enter</button>

            <div>
                <uL id="ul">
                    <li class="li"><input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name=""> Buy food for Siboo <button class="deleteBtn">Delete</button></li>
                    <li class="li"><input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name=""> Get a new controller <button class="deleteBtn">Delete</button></li>
                </uL><br>

                <button id="deleteAllBtn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete All Items</button>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        </div>
</body>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.strike {
    text-decoration: line-through;
   }
```

Here is my JS:

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("textBox");
var enterBtn = document.getElementById("enterBtn");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByClassName("li");
var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkBox");
var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteBtn");
var deleteAllBtn = document.getElementById("deleteAllBtn");

var itemsArray = localStorage.getItem('items') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) : [];

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

// Functions *********************

// Adding New Items to List - adding list element with checkbox and delete button *********************
function addNewItemToList(text)
{   
    itemsArray.push(textBox.value);
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
    liMaker(textBox.value);

}

function liMaker(text) {

    var newLi = document.createElement("li");
    newLi.textContent = text;
    newLi.className = "li";
    ul.appendChild(newLi);

    var createCheckBox = document.createElement("input");
    createCheckBox.type = "checkbox";
    createCheckBox.className = "checkBox";
    newLi.appendChild(createCheckBox);

    var createDeleteButton = document.createElement("button");
    var nameButtonDelete = document.createTextNode("Delete");
    createDeleteButton.appendChild(nameButtonDelete);
    createDeleteButton.className = "deleteBtn";
    newLi.appendChild(createDeleteButton);

}

data.forEach(item => {
    liMaker(item);
});


// CheckBox ELEMENT - click on checkBox to strike the list item off list*********************
function checkBoxFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
        checkBox[i].onclick = function () {
            this.parentNode.classList.toggle("strike");
        }}
}

// // DELETE BUTTON - click the delete button to delete the list item *********************
function deleteBtnFunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < deleteBtn.length; i++) {
        deleteBtn[i].onclick = function () {
            this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);

        }}
}

// DELETE ALL BUTTON - click the Delete ALl Items button to remove all items from the list *********************
function deleteAllBtnFunction()
{
    localStorage.clear();
    while (ul.firstChild) {
    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
  }
  itemsArray = [];
}

// TEXTBOX - press enter key to add an item to list *********************
function textBoxFunction()
{
    if (event.keyCode === 13 && textBox.value.length > 0)
    {
        addNewItemToList();
        textBox.value = "";
    }
    else if (event.keyCode === 13)
    {
        alert("Please enter an item to-do!");
    }
}

// ENTER BUTTON - click the enter button to add item to list *********************
function enterBtnFunction()
{
    if (textBox.value.length > 0)
    {
        addNewItemToList();
        textBox.value = "";
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please enter an item to-do!");
    }
}

listItemFunction();
deleteBtnFunction();

// Event Listeners *********************
textBox.addEventListener("keypress", textBoxFunction);
enterBtn.addEventListener("click", enterBtnFunction);
deleteAllBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteAllBtnFunction);
// End of Event Listeners *********************
```

Comment: What did you try so far? To delete a specific item from an array you could use the array method `filter` (or `splice` in conjunction with `indexOf`).

Comment: @subarachnid No it doesn't work, it either removes all the list items or none. Not a selected one.

Comment: I wrote a response demonstrating how it should work.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage.removeItem(/*key*/);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to remove a specific item and save the items to localstorage again:

```js
function removeItem(text) {
    var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items"));
    items = items.filter(function(e) {return e !== text; });
    localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
}

removeItem("itemname");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a professional but recently I created a todo app like this. I figured out after adding a new item, action listeners do not count them. So I inserted the event listeners inside the new element creation function after adding the element to the DOM.

Here is my suggestion

First, you have to link jQuery-3.2.1.slim.min.js to your project

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Put this code to the end of your liMaker function.

```
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           //Call your function
           console.log(this.id)
        }
     });
```

When creating the list element give each of them a unique id (add it to your checkbox). Maybe you can give them the array index.

```
createCheckBox.id ={unique id}
```

After doing that when you click the checkbox to invoke the above function. In that function `this.id` is the unique value you gave to the checkbox.
Then you can use it to remove that index from your array.

**Second Method (Pure JS)**
 Give a common class name to all checkboxes and a unique id also.

```
const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".{common_class_name}")

for(const cb of checkBoxes){
        button.addEventListener('click',function(){
            let id = this.id
            /*this id is the value you gave to the checkbox.
              Call your deleting methods here*/
        })
    }
```

Place this method at the end of your element creation method. This must run every time you add an element.

I copied your code and my method is working fine. I am a beginner there may be better ways to do that. but my method works.

Good Luck

Comment: Hey man, but I wanted to learn it in Pure JS without jquery. Do you happen to have any advice about doing it in JS?

Comment: Okay,  I will edit the answer, I have another way also